# Error parsing media type 'application/json;encoding=utf8, charset=utf-8'

Tags: java, json, rest, encoding, jersey

I'm using DropWizard with jersey to make a client that accepts JSON from a server and maps it to a POJO. However, I get this error when invoking the client.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error parsing media type 'application/json;encoding=utf8, charset=utf-8'
```

My code is as follows:

```
@Path("/something")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SampleClient {
  final Client client;
  WebResource.Builder builder;

  public SampleClient (Client client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.builder = client.resource("http://localhost/mysample/service").type("application/json");
  }

  @GET
  public MyMapper getSomething() {
   MyMapper result = builder.accept("application/json").get(MyMapper.class);
   return result;
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you generating that header in your client?

According to [W3C - 4 The Content-Type Header Field](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/4_Content-Type.html) the `Content-type` header must have the format:

```
Content-Type := type "/" subtype *[";" parameter]
```

where

```
parameter := attribute "=" value
```

So you *could* have as a parseable media type:

```
Content-type: application/json; encoding=utf8; charset=utf8
```

Using a semicolon instead of a comma. This doesn't mean it's correct, just parseable. Try using instead:

```
Content-type: application/json; charset=utf8
```

If that's a client error, then you might need to configure an `Accept` header (and the Content-type is not necessary since you aren't sending any payload). Try it without specifying the charset (if it fails, it will fail for another reason). You can test different headers and encodings using an interactive REST client, such as the [Firefox REST client](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/)

Comment: Changing both `.type(...)` and `.accept(...)` to `application/json; charset=utf8` did not help either. btw my client is consuming this service: `http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?name=taj`

Comment: I got it. It's the server that's returning both parameters in the Content-type. It works OK with the Firefox REST client. I'll check it here with another client.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using POSTMAN on chrome and it is showing me the data fine as well. However, my client in DropWizard/Jersey isn't able to parse it for some reason.

Comment: Are you generating that data in the server as well?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I have a client that is using Jersey. I make a call to the client like `http://localhost:9000/taj` my client reads the word `taj` and makes a request to `http://opentable.herokuapp.com/api/restaurants?name=taj` then maps the results onto a POJO and returns the POJO as a JSON object. The error happens when my client makes the request to the URL.

Comment: I've tried all my REST apps and none of them generate a duplicate encoding/charset Content-type header like the restaurants one.

Comment: Did you try matching your client-side media type declarations to the server one? I mean, perhaps you could try using "application/json; encoding=utf8, charset=utf-8" in the places where you have "application/json".

Comment: I was able to fix my errors. Apparently Jersey is a real stickler when it comes to Content-Type. Since the server is providing a content-type not compliant with the standards, jersey refuses to map it. So I had to write a filter to overwrite the content-type. as noted here: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/java-lang-IllegalArgumentException-Error-parsing-media-type-td3091556.html Thanks for your help

Comment: I just noted that the Firefox tester ignores invalid HTTP headers, accepting anything after ';' which is somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to remove the comma "," in the Content-type string

Or, you need to wrap the comma in double quotes

example

Content-type: video/mp4; codecs="avc1.64001F,mp4a.40.2"

the "comma" in "codecs" has to be wrapped in double-quotes